# Changing div text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a div, I would like to change the text inside it to `New Text`.

How can I do that with jquery

```
$('#mydiv').????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind an event and handle it:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    $(this).html("New Text");
});
```

Or use `bind`

```
$('#mydiv').bind("click", function() {
    $(this).html("New Text");
});
```

Or `live`

```
$('#mydiv').live("click", function() {
    $(this).html("New Text");
});
```

**References**

- [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)
- [Click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
- [Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(){
    this.innerHTML = "New Text";
});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9EJM/)

if you have something to chain, you can do it this way,

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    $(this).html("New Text") // can include html tags, use .text() for text only.
        .animate({marginLeft: '+=10'}); // chain an animation...
});
```

## [crazy demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9EJM/1/)

Comment: Is there any difference between `.innerHTML` and `.html` as answered by @kchau

Comment: @vinny - `.innerHTML` is a property of a `DOM` element while `.html` is a jQuery method. Native browser method or property is way faster than any javascript framework's method.

Comment: .html is forgiving of manipulating a table's contents and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mydiv').click(function() {
    $(this).html("New Text");
});
```

Comment: Is there any difference between `.html` and `.innerHTML` as answered by @Reigel

Comment: @vinny: innerHTML is faster in this case. You don't need a jQuery object to change all contents directly, it's a simple task.

Comment: In either case, the performance difference is negligible... I just used jQuery because that's what your question asked for.